# Highchart not display correct size on initial load, only resize when resizing window in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts, window-resize, react-highcharts

currently I am developing chart in my React. I am using Highchart. My problem is when my chart first loaded, the size is not following the container size, when i resize the window then only the chart display correct size.

many solution suggested to use

```
 chart.reflow();
```

but how to use this in react code?

i have tried

```
.highcharts-container, .highcharts-container svg {
  width: 100% !important;
}
```

not working

the chart always when initial will look like this[image]

I need the chart fully to the yellow line

My chart code

```
 this.setState({
  chartDrawSector: {
    chart: {
      type: 'column',
      height: '600',
      events: {
        load: function(event) {
          event.target.reflow();// i tried this not working also..
        }
      }
    },
    title: {
      text: 'Sector All'
    },
    // subtitle: {
    //   text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com'
    // },
    xAxis: {
      categories: sectorName[0],
      crosshair: true
    },
    yAxis: {
      min: 0,
      title: {
        text: displayMode == 'f' ? 'Figures' : 'Percentage %'
      }
    },
    tooltip: {
      headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
      pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
        '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.1f} </b></td></tr>',
      footerFormat: '</table>',
      shared: true,
      useHTML: true
    },
    plotOptions: {
      column: {
        pointPadding: 0.2,
        borderWidth: 0
      }
    },
    series: [{
      name: 'Ultimate Negative',
      data: n30Data[0],
      color: 'rgb(100, 30, 22 )'

    }, 
    {
      name: 'Ultimate Positive',
      data: gt30Data[0],
      color: 'rgb(27, 79, 114)'

    },

    ]
  }
})
```

Comment: you have specified chart height as 600. try removing it from chart config.

Comment: Hi I tried.. but the chart become more smaller..

Comment: Could you reproduce your case on some online editor with the sample data? You can start from this template: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-nwseym?file=index.js